# react / redux debounce throttling

Tags: reactjs, redux, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce a component in my webapp. Actually it is a filter for the maxPrice and if the user starts to print, the filter starts to work and all the results disappear until there is a reasonable number behind it.

What I tried so far:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

class MaxPrice extends Component {
  onSet = ({ target: { value }}) => {
    if (isNaN(Number(value))) return;

    this.setState({ value }, () => {
        this.props.updateMaxPrice(value.trim());
    });
  };

  render() {
    const updateMaxPrice = _.debounce(e => {
      this.onSet(e);
    }, 1000);

    return (
      <div>
        <ControlLabel>Preis bis</ControlLabel><br />
        <FormControl type="text" className={utilStyles.fullWidth} placeholder="egal"
          onChange={updateMaxPrice} value={this.props.maxPrice}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
MaxPrice.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at MaxPrice._this.onSet (MaxPrice.js:11)
at MaxPrice.js:21
at invokeFunc (lodash.js:10350)
at trailingEdge (lodash.js:10397)
at timerExpired (lodash.js:10385)
```

In my old version I had `onChange={this.onSet}` and it worked.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the initial state?

Comment: I'm using redux and the reducer should actually set the state. It worked before I added the debounce component. this.props.maxPrice is given through redux.

Comment: No, redux has nothing to do with state. Redux only provide props on connected component.

Comment: OK as I understand redux provides the default value through this.props.maxPrice. In my application it is just an empty string. Is there another state that I should take care on?

Comment: maybe I should somhow persist the event. Getting that I should use event.persist() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, it's required to use `event.persist()` to use event object in async way:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

It means such code, for example:

```
onChange={e => {
  e.persist();
  updateMaxPrice(e);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution. Thanks to lunochkin!

I had to introduce a second redux variable so that the user see's the values he is entering. The second variable is debounced so that the WepApp waits a bit to update.

```
class MaxPrice extends Component {

  updateMaxPriceRedux = _.debounce((value) => { // this can also dispatch a redux action
      this.props.updateMaxPrice(value);
  }, 500);

  onSet = ({ target: { value }}) => {
    console.log(value);
    if (isNaN(Number(value))) return;
    this.props.updateInternalMaxPrice(value.trim());
    this.updateMaxPriceRedux(value.trim());
  };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ControlLabel>Preis bis</ControlLabel><br />
                <FormControl type="text" className={utilStyles.fullWidth} placeholder="egal"
                             onChange={e => {
                                 e.persist();
                                 this.onSet(e);
                             }} value={this.props.internalMaxPrice}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        maxPrice: state.maxPrice,
        internalMaxPrice: state.internalMaxPrice
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({updateMaxPrice:updateMaxPrice,
        updateInternalMaxPrice:updateInternalMaxPrice}, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MaxPrice);
```